# How are tableaux presented here?

Tags: support, mathjax

How are tableaux presented here?

As a test I tried doing this:

```
    $$\Tree
    [.{\framebox{$(p \supset q)$} \\
    \framebox{$(r \lor \neg q)$} \\
    $\neg r$ \\
    $\neg p$}
    [.{$\neg p$}
    [.{$r$}
    [.{$\otimes$}
    ]
    ]
    [.{$\neg q$}
    ]
    ]
    [.{$q$}
    [.{$r$}
    [.{$\otimes$}
    ]
    ]
    [.{$\neg q$}
    [.{$\otimes$}
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]$$
```

which, of course, didn't work. I couldn't find a guide of any sort so I'm sorry if this is unnecessary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Best of luck! Urk. Neither MathJax nor Markdown seem likely to be very good at this sort of thing.

Comment: You could typeset it elsewhere and do a screen capture and cropping and embed it as an imgur image. Apparently stackoverflow etc integrates imgur very well(though, the details will have to be looked up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following one of the answer above (using my phone), I get the following.

[image: Tableau]

The code is the same.

[This site's pretty good if you want to provide the code.](https://www.writelatex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, they aren't. The tree/graph/graphic packages for TeX are not supported by MathJax. [From their site](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#unrecognized-TeX):

> Keep in mind that MathJax is meant for typesetting **math** on the web. It only replicates the math functionality of LaTeX and not the text formatting capabilities.  Any text formatting on the web should be done in HTML and CSS, not TeX.

I'm quite sure I've read a few posts on the MathJax mailing list that stated that tikz-like features are not among the goals of MathJax.

You could of course make your tableau in TeX, compile it, take a screenshot, and upload that. But this has a downside (besides being convoluted): it largely defeats the purpose of the editing feature.

On the other hand, there are initiatives like [XyJax](http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html), which is a limited port of the `xypic` package to MathJax. So you could try to recruit some adept JavaScript programmer to port your favourite tableau writing package to be suitable for MathJax.

But even then, you'd have to get this ported package approved of by the SE team, which often proves to be a big hurdle for this type of request.

---

In conclusion, I'm afraid that you'll have to work around this limitation.

At least for expository purposes, the screenshot method is quite reasonable, if you're willing to make the effort.

Comment: If you take a screenshot, please also include or link to the source code!

Comment: Does SE support SVG?

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you. It'd be great if there was an app for this.

Comment: @dfeuer Not that I know of. Would be great if it did, though (also for TeX.SE). And while at it, an online TeX compiler and source code hosting would be appreciated... but it's unlikely that SE thinks that's worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no good answer, I'll suggest a bad one:

> 1) You see,
>
> > 2) you can make a sort of
> >
> > > 3) tree structure in
> >
> > 4) MarkDown if you're okay with it
>
> 5) being really ugly.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks. I'd have put each branch separately otherwise, trimming things wherever sensible.