# Tableau as an answer

Tags: support, mathjax

I was not sure whether to ask this question here or the main Math SE. Regardless, please do move it as you see fit. I wanted to answer a question; however, I could not because  I don't know how to create tableau trees in Mathjax. I would appreciate if someone would tell me how to, or if it is at all possible.

Regards

Comment: Why do you think this is even possible? MathJax is a fairly limited syntax.

Comment: [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23055) contains a discussion on drawing a tree with MathJax. I think you'd be much better off using a separate program, like [GraphViz](http://www.webgraphviz.com/), though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So its not, Thanks for letting me know. To be honest, I don't know why i thought it was even possible.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Damn, mathjax one seems seems atrocious. I will try graph wiz, thanks.

Comment: [Here's how I did it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816821/104041)

Comment: @Shaun Thanks, that helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: [Related (if not a duplicate).](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11528/104041)

Comment: I think this link may help you https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/how-can-i-draw-a-tree-like-this